# Numpy array: Changing the values of the last column when lines of a 2d-array are equal to lines of another 2d-array

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy

I have huge 2D numpy array (called DATA). I want to change the last value (column) of all lines of DATA if those ones are similar to a same shaped external line (called ExtLine).

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import numpy

DATA=numpy.array([
    [1,2,3,4,5,6,0],
    [2,5,6,84,1,6,0],
    [9,9,9,9,9,9,0],
    [1,2,3,4,5,6,0],
    [2,5,6,84,1,6,0],
    [0,2,5,4,8,9,0]  ])
# Pool of lines that will be compared to DATA
PoolOfExtLines=numpy.array([[1,2,3,4,5,6,0],[2,5,6,84,1,6,0]])

for j in xrange(PoolOfExtLines.shape[0]):   # loop on pool of lines
    # convert ExtLine into a continous code (to be compare to future lines of DATA
    b=numpy.ascontiguousarray(PoolOfExtLines[j]).view(numpy.dtype((numpy.void, PoolOfExtLines[j].dtype.itemsize * PoolOfExtLines[j].shape[0])))

    for i in xrange(DATA.shape[0]):     # loop on DATA lines
        # convert the current line into a continous code (to be compare to b)
        a=numpy.ascontiguousarray(DATA[i]).view(numpy.dtype((numpy.void, DATA[i].dtype.itemsize * DATA[i].shape[0])))
        if a == b:
            DATA[i,-1]=-1
```

it results into a DATA arrays modified as I want (tag -1 at the end of lines that where similar to those of PoolOfExtLines:

```
  [[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6, -1],
   [ 2,  5,  6, 84,  1,  6, -1],
   [ 9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  0],
   [ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6, -1],
   [ 2,  5,  6, 84,  1,  6, -1],
   [ 0,  2,  5,  4,  8,  9,  0]]
```

My question: I feel that this code can be enhance and is quite complicated in regard to what I want to do. I feel that using some (built-in) methods I missed or smart direct (how?) comparisons, I can make the code clearer and faster. Thanks for your incoming help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`NumPy's broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) capability alongwith [`boolean indexing`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays) to solve it in a vectorized manner -

```
DATA[((DATA == PoolOfExtLines[:,None,:]).all(2)).any(0),-1] = -1
```

Sample run -

```
In [17]: DATA
Out[17]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  0],
       [ 2,  5,  6, 84,  1,  6,  0],
       [ 9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  0],
       [ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  0],
       [ 2,  5,  6, 84,  1,  6,  0],
       [ 0,  2,  5,  4,  8,  9,  0]])

In [18]: PoolOfExtLines
Out[18]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  0],
       [ 2,  5,  6, 84,  1,  6,  0]])

In [19]: DATA[((DATA == PoolOfExtLines[:,None,:]).all(2)).any(0),-1] = -1

In [20]: DATA
Out[20]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6, -1],
       [ 2,  5,  6, 84,  1,  6, -1],
       [ 9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  0],
       [ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6, -1],
       [ 2,  5,  6, 84,  1,  6, -1],
       [ 0,  2,  5,  4,  8,  9,  0]])
```

Comment: Great help, thanks! Very nice pedagogical answer and links.